# Issue in display media preview in sharing the link in Javascript code for Django project

Tags: javascript, django, image, html5-video, media

I am using below code snippet in my media gallery project :

```
{% block head %}
<meta property="og:title" content="{{image.title}}">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ image.file.url }}">
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ image.description }}">
{% endblock %}
```

But, when i am sharing the link on social media, i am only seeing the description of image and not the image preview .
Screenshot of image link share to facebook:
[image: Screenshot of image link share to facebook]

Please help.

Testable Example of the link :
https://pixzium.com/photo_detail/priyanka_br/sun-rising-above-sea-and-boat

Comment: **(1)** Show a testable example of the link... **(2)** The link page itself must have the OG tags then you just share a link to that page. Facebook checks the linked page for images.

Comment: @VC.One Here is the link: https://pixzium.com/photo_detail/priyanka_br/sun-rising-above-sea-and-boat

Comment: **(1)** Try to upload a separate smaller copy of image as thumbnail. Your image is too big (so Facebook will ignore it). Try re-scaling to a width of 1200 (and proportional height). **(2)** Facebook expects around `2:1` ratio (meaning the width must be twice the size of height). The correct FBook ratio of W:H is actually `1.9:1`... Note that Twitter expects a `1:1` square image (same width & height). Investigate what each "social media" site expects for thumbnail. **(3)** Since your image is from `https` server try adding also `og:image:secure_url` and provide same https link of the thumbnail.

Comment: @VC.One Compressing the image works for now, size less than 500 KB is showing preview now. But what if user uploads bigger image?